# Complex Dictionary blocked Xcode compile operation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, compiler-optimization

xCode 7.1 + swift2.1 + iOS 9.0
Code  below  block the Xcode compile operation.

```
let dic_1:Dictionary<String,Int> = ["key":200]
print("dic_1---->\(dic_1)")
```

Has this happened to anyone ?How does this happen?

---

Thanks for correcting grammer.

I found that it's not the reason the code above.

My origin code is below:

```
let dic_1 = [
    "status": 200,
    "info": "1234",
    "data":[

        "st_id":"st_id",
        "st_name":"radiant",
        "address":"dire",
        "longitude":"122.111",
        "latitude":"123.000000",
        "is_favorite":"0",
        "score":"5",
        "thumbnail":"www.baidu.com",
        "comment_count":"45612",
        "cert_img_url":"www.baidu.com",
        "has_inspay":"1",
        "has_car_discount":"1",
        "has_groupon":"1",
        "score_environment":"4.5",
        "score_service":"5.0",
        "score_oil":"5.0",
        "type":"98",
        "city":"SHENZHEN",
        "show_price_discount":"1",
        "is_support_invoice":"1",
        "price":[
            [
                "oil_name":"95#",
                "market_price":"6.23",
                "sell_price":"6.00",
                "wecar_price":"-100.00"
            ],
            [
                "oil_name":"95#",
                "market_price":"6.23",
                "sell_price":"6.00",
                "wecar_price":"-100.00"
            ],
            [
                "oil_name":"95#",
                "market_price":"6.23",
                "sell_price":"6.00",
                "wecar_price":"-100.00"
            ],

        ],

        "promotions": [
            "promotion1",
            "promotion1",
            "promotion1",
            "promotion1"
        ],
        "gpns":[
            [
                "gpn_id":"75642",
                "gpn_name":"gpn_name",
                "oil_type":"95",
                "price":"180",
                "sell_amount":"20000000",
                "old_price":"200"
            ]
        ],
        "discount_items":[

            [
                "desc":"It's a descrition.",
                "disc_type":"1"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

print("dic_1---->\(dic_1)")
```

Playground is running running,never figure out anything.So does this happen in iOS project.No error,just  running.

Comment: have you tried to let swift figure out the type by itself?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the leading single quote characters

Comment: What is the error message? The code works fine in playground

Comment: After the edit of @sasquatch which removed the single quotes the error has probably gone.

Comment: I was puzzled.The simple Dictionary works fine @AnthonyKong today.The complex Dictionary still blocks the compile operation.

Comment: I have no problem with the complex dictionary either. Make sure you are using the latest Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a complex nested structure for the `data` key so Swift's type inference system failed. In my Xcode 7.1.1, it gives a "Type is ambiguous without more context" error.

Give the compiler a hint as to the data type:

```
let data: [String: Any] = [
    "st_id":"st_id",
    "st_name":"radiant",
    "address":"dire",
    "longitude":"122.111",
    "latitude":"123.000000",
    "is_favorite":"0",
    "score":"5",
    "thumbnail":"www.baidu.com",
    "comment_count":"45612",
    "cert_img_url":"www.baidu.com",
    "has_inspay":"1",
    "has_car_discount":"1",
    "has_groupon":"1",
    "score_environment":"4.5",
    "score_service":"5.0",
    "score_oil":"5.0",
    "type":"98",
    "city":"SHENZHEN",
    "show_price_discount":"1",
    "is_support_invoice":"1",
    "price":[
        [
            "oil_name":"95#",
            "market_price":"6.23",
            "sell_price":"6.00",
            "wecar_price":"-100.00"
        ],
        [
            "oil_name":"95#",
            "market_price":"6.23",
            "sell_price":"6.00",
            "wecar_price":"-100.00"
        ],
        [
            "oil_name":"95#",
            "market_price":"6.23",
            "sell_price":"6.00",
            "wecar_price":"-100.00"
        ],

    ],

    "promotions": [
        "promotion1",
        "promotion1",
        "promotion1",
        "promotion1"
    ],
    "gpns":[
        [
            "gpn_id":"75642",
            "gpn_name":"gpn_name",
            "oil_type":"95",
            "price":"180",
            "sell_amount":"20000000",
            "old_price":"200"
        ]
    ],
    "discount_items":[

        [
            "desc":"It's a descrition.",
            "disc_type":"1"
        ]
    ]
]

let dic_1: [String: Any] = [
    "status": 200,
    "info": "1234",
    "data": data
]
```

Comment: It's the answer.My Xcode hasn't compiled the error. Is it the reason of  my Build Setting? I use the default settings. Should I need to turn on other warnings ?

Comment: I used the default build settings as well. My Xcode version is 7.1.1. What's yours?

Comment: My Xcode version is 7.1.1   too. It hasn't complain the error.

 To speed compiling,Give the compiler a hint as to the data type.

Comment: Hm... I have no idea why you and I see different error messages